# Can you put multiple extra_text's in an android emailIntent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Is it possible to put multiple multiple EXTRA_TEXT's...

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Text1");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Text2");
```

like so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can send only on EXTRA_TEXT in an Intent, instead you can send like this,

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder().append("<p>Text1</p>").append("<p> Text2 </p").toString()));
```

Comment: I have to put a whole terms and conditions into an email. I have them saved in 4 different strings in my strings.xml file, is there anyway for me to like use those instead of whole paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Extras are basically a fancy `HashMap`. There is only one value per key, and the last value set for that key "wins". So, in your case, the value of `EXTRA_TEXT` will be `"Text2"`.